# Transformar función de API a asíncrona

Tags: nodejs, api

Estoy desarrollando una API en NodeJS con Express y ahora que termine todas las funciones y está todo OK quiero hacer que sea asíncrono.

En este momento el flujo es así:

Tengo una carpeta **routes** donde por ejemplo hay un archivo llamado **productRoute.js**, este archivo tiene una función como esta:

```
const { getProducts } = require('../services/productService');

app.get('/producto', function(req, res) {
        getProducts(req, res);
    })
```

De acá va al servicio de productos, en la carpeta **services** dentro de archivo llamado **productService.js** y a la siguiente función:

```
let getProducts = (req, res) => {
    let pagina = Number(req.query.pagina) || 1;
    let cantidad = Number(req.query.cantidad) || 10;
    let query = { estado: true };
    let { codigo, descripcion, nombre } = req.query;
    if ( codigo ) { query.codigo = new RegExp(codigo, "i") };
    if ( nombre ) { query.nombre = new RegExp(nombre, "i") };
    Producto.find(query, '_id codigo descripcion nombre precioCosto precioVenta categoria marca estado imagenBase64')
        .sort({nombre: 'asc'})
        .populate('categoria', '_id nombre')
        .populate('marca', '_id nombre')
        .skip((pagina * cantidad) - cantidad)
        .limit(cantidad)
        .exec((err, productos) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'Error interno en el servidor'
                });
            }
            if (!productos) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'No se encontraron productos.'
                    }
                });
            }

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                cantidad: productos.length,
                entidadResultante: productos
            });
        })
}
```

Ahora tengo entendido que mis funciones (hay muchos mas y todos de la misma forma), no son asíncronas ya que no estoy utilizando **async/await**, como podría pasar estas funciones a asíncronas? Hay alguna librería que me ayude en esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que tienes una pequeña confusión entre [Función tipo `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) y un proceso asíncrono o [asincronía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asincron%C3%ADa). Toda petición a una Base de Datos desde Javascript es y será siempre un proceso asíncrono. Para manejar los mismos puedes: **usar callbacks** tal como lo haces actualmente o **usar Promesas** (el método `exec()` de los Modelos de Mongoose devuelven una Promesa si no pasas un callback). ¿Qué intentas conseguir? Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio! Gracias por tu respuesta. Es muy probable que me este confundiendo ya que empece hace poco con NodeJS (JS en general). Lo que tenía pretendido hacer es que al recibir una consulta a la API, esta pueda seguir tomando otras consultas diferentes sin bloquearse (basicamente lo que queremos en toda API, que pueda recibir consultas e ir respondiendolas a medida que tengan una respuesta para dar). Por lo que entiendo, al estar escribiendo las funciones con callbacks, la API no se bloquea en una función mientras espera la respuesta de la DB?

Comment: Javascript evita el bloqueo precisamente haciendo uso de funciones `callback` tal como las usas actualmente en tu código. Por lo tanto tus métodos no son para nada *bloqueantes*. Al contrario, te permiten siempre manejar una solicitud nueva ya que son manejadas por la función `callback` adecuada. El cambio de `callback` a Promesas es sólo un cambio en el estilo de código, pero la funcionalidad será exactamente la misma. Saludos

Comment: Genial! Gracias por sacarme la duda, pensé que todavía eran síncronas las funciones y no quería que quede así. Muchas gracias.